# может кто то обьяснить как make gcc < 5

Tags: gcc

одна из програм которую я собираюсь использовать требует для сборки g++ версии ниже 5
что я делаю:
скачал исходники отсюда
https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/mirrors/gnu/mirror/gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/
распаковал в папку
и далее использую

```
tar xzf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.8.5
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.5/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-4.8.5 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
make
make install
```

Получаю различные ошибки

```
In file included from /home/user/gcc/objdir/../gcc-4.8.5/gcc/cp/except.c:1008:
cfns.gperf:101:1: error: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ redeclared inline with ‘gnu_inline’ attribute
cfns.gperf:26:14: note: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ previously declared here
cfns.gperf:26:14: warning: inline function ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ used but never defined
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1059: cp/except.o] Ошибка 1
```

как собрать gcc -v < 5